# "stands out from" (some others) "by" or "with" (some distinctive feature)?

Tags: prepositions

Should I use "by" or "with" as a proposition connecting a statement about somebody standing out with the description of their distinctive feature that makes them stand out?

For example,

> Henry kind of stands out from the rest of this class **with(?)/by(?)** his ability to come up
>   with quick and spontaneous answers to the teacher's questions, which
>   at times turn out to be so funny, that they can refreshen the tone of
>   the whole remainder of the lesson time.

Comment: We would say simply **the remainder of the lesson**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **in** there, or **for**, but **with** and **by** are both grammatical, though **by** is shading into marginal territory.

P.S. **stands out**, although it is predicated of Henry, is on a semantic level predicated of those beholding him.  It means "is (more) noticeable", that is, noticeable *to those taking note*. That's why **by** is marginal. It's like saying *The cardinal is easy to see against the brown of the leafless trees **by** its bright red coloration*.  **by** is a shade "off" there with **see**, and yet if we change **see** to **recognize** or **discern** or **pick out** it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - it shows the logic behind the usage.